# Object manipulation using EclipseLink MOXy

Tags: java, xml, object, eclipselink, moxy

I've two set set of almost identical employee xsds, using which I used to generate Classes using jaxb2-maven-plugin.
These two are almost identical, except one is for admin and other one is for normal user.
1st xsd's xml looks like:

```
<Employee>
  <Head id="xxx" type="ADMIN"/>
  <Address type="HOME" from="dd-mm-yyyy">xxx</Address>
  <PayRate>34</PayRate>
</Employee>
```

2nd xsd's xml looks like:

```
<Employee>
  <Head id="xxx" type="WORKER"/>
  <Address type="HOME">xxx</Address>
</Employee>
```

As you can see there is no from tag(in the address tag) and PayRate in the 2nd xml.
I've a REST api open, where I always get the 1st formatted payload. But ***based on the employee type I need to convert it to the 2nd one using Eclipse MOXy***.

```
private static DynamicJAXBContext dynamicJAXBContext = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Employee-v1.xsd"), null, 
        com.something.Employee.class.getClassLoader(), null);

DynamicEntity dynamicEntity = (DynamicEntity) dynamicJAXBContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(employeePojoOfV2).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

com.something.Employee emp = new com.something.Employee();

emp.sethead(JAXB.unmarshal(dynamicEntity.get("Head"), Head.class));
emp.setAddress(JAXB.unmarshal(dynamicEntity.get("Address"), Address.class));
```

However, it's alwasy throwing following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.something.v2.Head cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.DynamicEntityImpl
```

Is this really achievable or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
DynamicEntity dynamicEntity = (DynamicEntity) dynamicJAXBContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(employeePojoOfV2).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

from the above code are you upgrading from version1 xsd to version 2 object by unmarshal?

Suggestion :

better you can go with **Xstream** to do the *Marshalling/unMarshalling*  easily when you need to downgrade just use the `xstream.addImplicitCollection` function for particular/whatever fields are need to be ignore while Marshalling from the object to xml.

Sample Program:

```
<customer>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
    <dob>1986-02-14 04:14:05.874 UTC</dob>
    <contactDetailsList>
        <ContactDetails>
            <mobile>6673543265</mobile>
            <landline>0124-2460311</landline>
        </ContactDetails>
        <ContactDetails>
            <mobile>4676543565</mobile>
            <landline>0120-223312</landline>
        </ContactDetails>
    </contactDetailsList>
</customer>
```

Let’s suppose we need to omit the contactDetailsList parent tags, and we just want each ContactDetails element to be a child of the customer element. Let us modify our example again:

```
xstream.addImplicitCollection(Customer.class, "contactDetailsList");
```

Output:

```
<customer>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
    <dob>1986-02-14 04:14:20.541 UTC</dob>
    <ContactDetails>
        <mobile>6673543265</mobile>
        <landline>0124-2460311</landline>
    </ContactDetails>
    <ContactDetails>`enter code here`
        <mobile>4676543565</mobile>
        <landline>0120-223312</landline>
    </ContactDetails>
</customer>
```